# asynchronous commenting without refreshing the page

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

im trying to make a comment system what im trying to do is to send a comment to a post and will pop up right away after sending but i dont know exactly how to do it.. what i did was when i send a comment i use `window.location.reload` to pop up my comment

```
<div id="mycomments">
<?php 
  foreach ($post_model->getcomment() as $value) {
  if($postid == $value['post_uid']){

?>

  <div class="col-lg-12" style="background:#eff9c7;">
  <img src="./<?php echo $value['image']?>" class="pull-left" style="border-radius:50%;margin-top:10px;" width="7%" height="7%" />
  <p style="margin-top:18px;line-height:15px;"><strong class="font-1" style="margin-left:10px;"><?php echo $value['firstname'].' '.$value['lastname']?></strong> <?php echo $value['pc_comment']?><br>
  <span class="" style="margin-left:10px;font-size:.9em;color:gray;"><abbr class="timeago" title="<?php echo $value['pc_datesend']?>"></abbr></span> 
  </p>
  </div>


<?php
}
}
?>
</div>
```

with this code i can show my comment 
and with sending the comment i use this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('input[name="mycomment"]').on('keyup', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var comments = $(this).val();
        var sid = $(this).closest("div#userspost").find("input[type='hidden']").val();

        if(e.keyCode == 13){

            if(comments.length)
                $.ajax({
                  url: "../controller/post_controller.php",
                  type: "POST",
                  data:{ 
                  "id":sid,
                  "comments":comments,

                  },
                    success: function(data)
                  {
                    window.location.reload();

                  }
                });

            else
                alert("Please write something in comment.");
        }

    });
});
```

this is where i send my request.

**post_controller.php**

```
<?php
if(session_id() == '' || !isset($_SESSION))
session_start();
$session_id = $_SESSION['id'];


  require_once('../model/dbconfig.php');
  require_once('../model/post.php');
  $database = new Database();
  $conn = $database->getConnection();
  $com = new post($conn);
    $comments = ($_POST['comments']);
  $uid = ($_POST['id']);
 if(isset($_POST['id']) && isset($_POST['comments'])){

    $res = $com->comment($uid,$session_id,$comments);
  }
?>
```

what i want to do is when i send a comment it will show right after i send the comment and it will show like this [image]

i tried using  `$("#mycomments").append(data);` but what happen is it only display the query of my db to insert the comment.. but not the html format.

Comment: why are you using ajax if you are refreshing the page?

Comment: i use ajax to send the input value to my sql query

Comment: why not use a get request or a redirect?

Comment: the only problem that i need to be solve is that how can i display the comment with the html format using append. like the picture above. cause when i tried to use append what the append display is the query of my sql.

Comment: build the comment in the controller and return it to the page

Comment: i already did.. my problem is the html format for the comment how to append with the html format

Comment: i don't see any html returned from you post_controller

Comment: yeah it is not from post_controller i use forloop to display the returned data from post_controller to the other script. that is how i display the sample picture.. but what i wanted to do is to use the same style in `.append`